# Jasmine cannot find function when creating spy

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How to create spy for the below line of code

```
this.$('#crumb').dropdown('toggle');
```

i have tried using : `spyOn($, 'dropdown');`

but getting below error message

```
TypeError: this.$(...).dropdown is not a function
```

Comment: Why is `jQuery` defined under `this`? Could you provide a [MCVE example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i guess it's [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)

Comment: have you tried spyOn($.fn, "dropdown"); ?

Comment: @eramit2010 not working .

Answer (score 0):

In the Karma config file, you need to add the file paths from vendor or `node_modules` folder:

```
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
```